# Scraping Tweets in R httr, jsonlite, dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, twitter, httr, jsonlite

This is my code:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)

bearer_token <- Sys.getenv("BEARER_TOKEN")
headers <- c('Authorization' = sprintf('Bearer %s', bearer_token))

params <- list('expansions' = 'attachments.media_keys')

handle <- readline('BenDuBose')
url_handle <-
  sprintf('https://api.twitter.com/2/users/by?username=%s', handle)

response <-
  httr::GET(url = url_handle,
            httr::add_headers(.headers = headers),
            query = params)
obj <- httr::content(response, as = "text")
print(obj)
```

This is my error message:

> [1] "{"errors":[{"parameters":{"ids":[""]},"message":"The number of values in the `ids` query parameter list [0] is not between 1 and 100"}],"title":"Invalid Request","detail":"One or more parameters to your request was invalid.","type":"https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/invalid-request"}"

My end goal is to scrape an image from a specific tweet ID/user.  I already have a list of users and tweet IDs, along with attachments.media_keys.  But, I don't know how to use HTTR and I am trying to copy the Twitter Developer example verbatim to learn, but it isn't working.

Comment: Just from reading your error message, it sounds like your `ids` list contains values that are not in the allowed range 1–100. Would you mind providing the content of the query parameter object 'params'?

Comment: Have you tried using a package like "twitteR" (there are other options) to access the information as opposed to starting from scratch?